# Python MySQL Query Not working (Something went wrong format requires a mapping)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask, pymysql

I am trying to pull a query from my database and I am receiving this error when trying to run it: Something went wrong format requires a mapping.

I'm using flask in Python and pymysql.

This is my class method that is throwing the error:

```
@classmethod
    def get_dojo(cls, data):
        query = 'SELECT * FROM dojos WHERE id = %(id)s;'
        result = connectToMySQL('dojos_and_ninjas').query_db(query, data)
        return cls(result[0])
```

I thought it might be the data I am passing through but it looks good to me, and the query runs fine in workbench. I tried restarting MySQL, VS Code, and restarting the pipenv.

The data I am passing is:

```
@app.route('/dojo/<int:id>')
def dojo_page(id):
    dojo_current = Dojo.get_dojo(id)
    return render_template('dojo_page.html', dojo = dojo_current)
```

My page will render and I receive no error when I enter an id in manually instead of calling the data into it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to add a data dictionary in the route.

```
@app.route('/dojo/<int:id>')
def dojo_page(id):
    data = {
        'id': id
    }
    dojo_current = Dojo.get_dojo(data)
    return render_template('dojo_page.html', dojo = dojo_current)
```